# Grizzly 2.2.19 FilterChain vs HttpHandler

Tags: java, servlets, soapui, grizzly

I'm attempting to implement a simple [Grizzly](https://grizzly.java.net/) web server that, upon receipt of an HTTP request, will:

- Process the specified filters
- Echo the request back to the sender

I am submitting the request from soapUI and seeing behavior that I don't expect:

*RunServer.java:*

```java
public class RunServer{
    public static final String HOST = "localhost";
    public static final int PORT = 5151;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer();

        NetworkListener listener = new NetworkListener("echoCalls", "localhost", 5151);

        FilterChainBuilder filterChainBuilder = FilterChainBuilder.stateless();

        filterChainBuilder.add(new TransportFilter());

        filterChainBuilder.add(new StringFilter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        //filterChainBuilder.add(new StringFilter(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
        //filterChainBuilder.add(new StringFilter(Charset.forName("ASCII")));

        filterChainBuilder.add(new MyEchoFilter());

        listener.setFilterChain(filterChainBuilder.build());

        server.addListener(listener);

        server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new MyEchoHandler(), "/echo");

        try{
            server.start();
            System.out.println("Press any key to stop the server...");
            System.in.read();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.println(ioe.toString());
        }finally{
            server.stop();
        }

    }

}
```

*MyEchoFilter.java:*

```java
public class MyEchoFilter extends BaseFilter{

    public NextAction handleRead(FilterChainContext ctx)throws IOException{

        System.err.println(">>>MyEchoFilter.handleRead()...");

        //|why not working? no response, eventual time out. soapui just hangs up after return NextAction...

        final Object peerAddress = ctx.getAddress();
        final Object message = ctx.getMessage();
        ctx.write(peerAddress, message, null);

        return ctx.getStopAction();
    }

    public NextAction handleWrite(FilterChainContext ctx) throws IOException{
        System.err.println(">>>MyEchoFilter.handleWrite()...");

        return ctx.getStopAction();
    }

    public NextAction handleConnect(FilterChainContext ctx) throws IOException{
        System.err.println(">>>MyEchoFilter.handleConnect()...");

        return ctx.getStopAction();
    }

    public NextAction handleAccept(FilterChainContext ctx) throws IOException{
        System.err.println(">>>MyEchoFilter.handleAccept()...");

        return ctx.getStopAction();
    }

    public NextAction handleClose(FilterChainContext ctx) throws IOException{
        System.err.println(">>>MyEchoFilter.handleClose()...");

        return ctx.getStopAction();
    }

}
```

*MyEchoHandler:*

```java
public class MyEchoHandler extends HttpHandler{

    public void service(Request req, Response res) throws Exception{

        System.err.println(">>>handler service method...");

        BufferedReader requestStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream()));

        String reqStrLn;
        StringBuffer callContent = new StringBuffer();
        while((reqStrLn = requestStream.readLine()) != null) callContent.append(reqStrLn);

        res.setContentLength(callContent.length());
        res.getWriter().write(callContent.toString());
    }
}
```

With the code above, as-is, the handleAccept() method is fired upon initiating a soapUI request. Strangely, the handleRead() method does **not** fire, unless I comment out the UTF-8 string filter, in RunServer:

```java
//filterChainBuilder.add(new StringFilter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

I can't figure that out, if anyone can explain, I would appreciate it.

But, more importantly, the service() method in MyEchoHandler does not fire either.

That only fires if I comment out the line that sets the FilterChain to the NetworkListener, in RunServer:

```java
//listener.setFilterChain(filterChainBuilder.build());
```

When I **do** avoid using a FilterChain, I actually do get a response back to soapUI, but I really need the FilterChain.

It may seem like I'm missing part of the point here, that I should be avoiding handlers all together, in favor of using filters, but I haven't been able to get a response back to soapUI while using filters.

Can anyone help me pinpoint the error of my ways?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you explain why you feel you need the custom FilterChain?  I would like to better understand what you're trying to accomplish before continuing.

Comment: I need the filter chain to add chunked encoding support

Answer (score 1):

As I ran into this issue as well and it really took me quite some time to figure out.

```
filterChainBuilder.add(new StringFilter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

StringFilter decodes/encodes strings as bytes and therefore uses a special length prefix. If the incoming messages cannot be decoded it gets skipped. Therefore it looks as if the method 'handleRead' does not fire.

Answer (score 0):

So, in short, the reason your HttpHandler isn't being invoked, is you're clobbering the FilterChain that is installed by default that provides the HttpHandler support.

As far as chunked encoding support, that's provided for you already.  If, at the time the response is committed, a content-length hasn't been set, then the response will use the chunked transfer-encoding.

Comment: I wish that were the case, I constantly get chunked encoding errors whenever I submit a 1.1 request. That's why I'm attempting to add in the ChunkedInputFilter.

Comment: I'd recommend logging an issue https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY/.  If you could link a test case via dropbox or some other sharing service (JIRA attachments are disabled), we can give you a hand.